# Merging two collections and generate a file in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am very new to the MongoDB. I am using MongoDB as my master database. In my database I have multiple collections and I am storing huge amount of data in my collections. Below are some of the collection names

- FirstName
- LastName
- Name
- Address
- IBAN
  etc...

I developed a client and that client will request data. Client will send an object based on that I need to generate the data and send it to client. Say for example, the client has an POJO class called **Person** and it has 3 fields. Those are FirstName, LastName and Name. The client will send this object as an argument to the server. My server code analyze that object and will pump the data to the client. Here my problem is, the data is present in multiple collections. How can club those 3 collections into one and how can I send that data.

I saw the multiple forums in internet and every one showing the map-reduce example. But in my case its not dealing with aggregate functions. So how can I fill the data before sending to the client.? Can any one help me on this.?

Thanks in advance,
Amar.T

Comment: You have a separate collection for each field? Why would you do that? Usually you would have on collection "Person" where each document has the fields FirstName, LastName, Address etc.

Comment: @Philipp, Along with the value I am maintaining some more information in each collection. I don't want to mix those into one collection in my master database. I have another scenario like say for example, the end-user has IBAN and SSN in one entity but those two are different collections in my case. I just want to know how can we handle in these scenarios.?

Comment: There is no trivial solution for what you describe. Please post literal examples of your documents and a more detailed description of what output you want. Maybe we can help you then.

Comment: I agree with @Philip. As a rule of thumb there should be a one to one mapping between your POJO class and the MongoDB collection unless you have a valid reason not to do so. Based on your current post,  splitting up first name, last name and name in separate collections does not appear to be an optimal design.

Comment: @Jaco, I will just provide the test data based on the end-user database schema. Its not possible to maintain the one to one mapping between the POJO and mongoDB collections because my server will accept any pojo object. My server will read that object dynamically (using reflections). 

So I faced this issue in one of the scenario. One of the end-user is maintaining SSN and IBAN in one entity. But those are two different collections in my database. Its very hard to say to the customer to change the schema. So how can we handle this kind of scenario.?

Answer (score 1):

You have different collections for each field and there is no common field in all the collections. How would it map firstname to its lastname. According to me, you have 2 options:

1. Merge all the collections because separately they make no sense.
2. Assign some common attribute like `person_id` to all the collections and assign them the same value for same person.

Comment: I am just a data provider. I will provide the data based on the users database schema. I will provide the data to do a load and functional test. So from my end there is no need to maintain any relationship between firstname and lastname. When ever the user asks for first name I will give that first name data and in the same way for last name as well. This way if user gave his schema I will provide the data based on that schema.

Comment: When you don't need to maintain any relationship between firstname and lastname, why do you need to merge data of two different collection then?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I would suggest you store your data in one collection. MongoDB documents are schema-less and each document can have a different schema. You should simply store all your fields in one collection, your find query will filter out the relevant results when querying.

Regarding the overhead, there will be little overhead storing all fields in one collections compared to using individual collections, however, there should be use performance gain when querying the data as joins between multiple collections will be slow.

Comment: At present I have 50 fields and millions of records. But may be in the future the count will increase. Is there any performance overhead if I maintain everything into one collection.?

Comment: There should be little overhead compared to storing these fields in separate collections. There will be a large performance gain though when reading the data as joining multiple collections will be slow.